# Screen sharing in native Android application using webrtc

Tags: android, webrtc, native-code, screensharing

I searched many documents but didn't find any exact solution for my problem. I want to implement audio call and screen sharing in Android native application using webrtc without using any third party sdk.

I found one demo example i.e apprtc but it supports only audio call. How to implement screen sharing too?

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem? If so, can you direct me in right direction in this regards.

Comment: @gnat.   No. I didn't get. only audio call is possible. Don't have any idea about screen sharing.

Answer (score 5):

This answer may be irrelevant for the OP, since the question is very old.

Anyway, for anyone in the future searching for something similar, check [this commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/b75f2541c942e2f35c3b7d7003ed17504176ced1) in webrtc repo. It adds a screen capturer for Android.

Comment: Thanks! May be irrelevant for the OP but helpful for community!

Comment: And now we also have Screen Share support : https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/ccf10219cd47c297c1f06f3b42cc1f7df68a24d3